# Inconsistency with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, plot

There is a problem when I try to draw something over an already done graph, like a parabola:
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[red, ultra thick] (x*x,x);
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Let's assume there is another constant at `x=-3`, so we would would expecte a vertical segment along the x value. Instead we get:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[red, ultra thick] (x*x,x);
  \draw[dashed,color=blue] (-3,-10) -- (-3,10);
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

and all that is done is the thin blue segment. I was expecting something more notable. Aren't all elements of tikzpicture supposed to be done in the same scale or using the same coordinate system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition about the coordinate system is correct. You have to prefix the coordinates by `axis cs:`.

```
\draw[dashed,color=blue] (axis cs:0,-4) -- (axis cs:25,2);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[red, ultra thick] (x*x,x);
  \draw[dashed,color=blue] (axis cs:0,-4) -- (axis cs:25,2);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is actually only needed if you run `pgfplots` in the backwards compatibility mode or if you use a very old version (earlier than `1.11`, we are now at `1.17`), neither of which is recommended. The cleaner way is to use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`.